# Any way to take a css value from another element, and add it with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

I am using this right now...

```
if($('.current').hasClass('odd') && !$('.current').hasClass('even')) {
                        var oddMarL = $('.current img').css('margin-left'); 
                        var oddMarL2 = $('.touch').css('margin-left'); 
                        var oddMarT = $('.touch').css('margin-top'); 

                        oddMarL.replace('px', '');
                        oddMarL2.replace('px', '');
                        oddMarT.replace('px', '');

                        Math.abs(oddMarL,oddMarL2,oddMarT);

                        oddMarL = oddMarL + oddMarL2;

                        $('#zoom').css('margin-left',oddMarL);
                        $('#zoom').css('margin-top',oddMarT);
                    }
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is it just not possible?

It works until I add the 2 values together or when I use math.abs. In the error console it says margin-left cannot be parsed.

I have reasons for needing it this way so please don't recommend using a class! :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` and `Math.max` functions don't work the way your code seems to assume they would. They *return* values:

```
oddMarL = oddMarL.replace('px', '');
```

and

```
oddMarL = Math.abs(parseInt(oddMarL, 10));
```

are necessary to actually change the values. You'd have to do the same thing with the other variables.

Comment: Also I'll note that you don't really have to strip the "px" if you're going to call `parseInt` because `parseInt` will just stop when it gets to the "p".

Answer (score -1):

try this also:

```
$('#zoom').css('margin-left',oddMarL+'px');
$('#zoom').css('margin-top',oddMarT+'px');
```

Comment: The browser will assume "px" anyway. The problem is that oddMarL is going to look like "12px15px" so adding yet another "px" can't help.

Comment: the px gets automatically put there, it messes up when I add the px